# Array of structures and pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

How are arrays of structures accessed using pointer arithmetic?

suppose I have a struct

```
struct point{
int x;
int y;
}collection[100];
```

Suppose I have a function

```
int func(struct point *collection,int size)
```

Inside this function I access the element as shown below.

```
collection[0].x
```

Is this the same as `*(collection + 0).x`? Since the `.` operator has higher precedence than the `*` operator, first the collection pointer is incremented by 0, and the the dot operator is applied, and then the pointer dereferenced? Somehow this does not make sense; any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: If you really want to bake your noodle, can you work out what `0[collection].x` is?

Comment: @Eric Lippert (*(0 + collection)).x, from what I gathered the [] operator means...a[5] = *(a+5) so 5[a] means *(5+a) therefore 0[collection].x is the same as collection[0].x took me some time, did I get it right.

Comment: You got it!  Indexing is just a fancy kind of addition, and addition is commutative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the same as `*(collection + 0).x`?

No. Your explanation is absolutely correct, `.` has higher precedence than `*`, so that second expression is parsed as `*((collection + 0).x)`. `collection[i].x` on the other hand is equivalent to `(*(collection + i)).x`.

Actually this awkwardness is the reason the `->` operator was introduced, so assuming `y` is some non-trivial expression, you can write

```
y->x
```

instead of

```
(*(y)).x
```

Although obviously `collection[0].x` is much cleaner than `(collection + 0)->x` in this particular instance.

Comment: (*(collection + i)).x, this makes much more sense now, so arrays of structures has an extra set of parenthesis before the dot operator when using pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @tesseract: Well I guess the essence is that if you have a pointer to the struct (for example `collection + i`, which is a pointer), and you want to access a field of the struct pointed to by your pointer, you need to *dereference* the pointer and then apply the dot operator to it. Since the dot operator has quite high precedence, you need to force the dereference using an explicit pair of brackets.